# Error after installing and running Pyspark for the first time (Another SparkContext is being constructed)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I recently installed pyspark on my Windows 10 64-bit machine, and while I am pretty sure I set everything up right, trying to run pyspark in the command line nets the following errors:

https://pastebin.com/LjLWZKUU

```
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
22/02/21 13:41:14 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
22/02/21 13:41:15 WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor). This may indicate an error, since only one SparkContext should be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
C:\apps\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\shell.py:42: UserWarning: Failed to initialize Spark session.
  warnings.warn("Failed to initialize Spark session.")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\apps\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\shell.py", line 38, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession._create_shell_session()  # type: ignore
  File "C:\apps\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 553, in _create_shell_session
    return SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  File "C:\apps\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 228, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "C:\apps\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\context.py", line 392, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "C:\apps\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\context.py", line 146, in __init__
    self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
  File "C:\apps\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\context.py", line 209, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "C:\apps\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\context.py", line 329, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "C:\apps\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1585, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "C:\apps\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:348)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:336)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
 
 
C:\Users\Luci>SUCCESS: The process with PID 8328 (child process of PID 12148) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 12148 (child process of PID 10712) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 10712 (child process of PID 6336) has been terminated.
```

My only real guess is that there's a problem with how I have installed something or set up an environment variable but everything I have tried has failed. I have tried to remove everything I installed and do it again, restarting my computer, restarting the command prompt, and while I have tried killing any ongoing Spark Sessions in my Python IDE I cannot seem to use the SparkSession.stop() command correctly, so that is a dead end too. I'm going to post my variable paths for SPARK_HOME, HADOOP_HOME, JAVA_HOME, as well as the variables I added to Path just in case there is something wrong there.

JAVA_HOME:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2

SPARK_HOME:
C:\apps\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2

HADOOP_HOME:
C:\apps\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2

PATH Variables:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2
C:\apps\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\bin

there seem to be some other things in the PATH variable related to Java like older versions of JDK, I'm not sure if that's what's causing the error as well maybe? Hopefully someone can help, I've given as much information as I can think to give but if you need anything else just let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is due to 2 conflicting setup for pyspark. Do you have anaconda installed? If so you may try the following commands

> conda uninstall pyspark
> pip install pyspark

I ran into a similar issue and the above commands helped me get out of it (after several hours & trying multiple things)